# Awk if else expression not printing correct results for mathematical operation

Tags: variables, if-statement, math, awk

So I have an input file that looks like this:

```
atom    Comp
C1  45.7006
H40 30.0407
N41 148.389
S44 502.263
F45 365.162
```

I also have some variables that I have called in from another file, which I know are defined correctly, as the correct values print when I call them using echo.

These values are

```
Hslope=-1.1120
Hint=32.4057
Cslope=-1.0822
Cint=196.4234
```

What I am trying to do is to for all lines with C in the first column, print  (column 2 - Cint)/Cslope. The same for all lines with H in the first column with the appropriate variables and have all lines that don't have C or H print "NA".

The first line should be skipped.

Currently, my code reads

```
awk -v Hslope=$Hslope -v Hint=$Hint -v Cslope=$Cslope -v Cint=$Cint '{for(i=2; i<=NR; i++) 
{
    if($1 ~ /C/) 
    { shift = (($2-Cint)/Cslope); print shift } 
    else if($1 ~ /H/) 
    { shift = (($2-Hint)/Hslope); print shift } 
    else 
   { print "NA" }
} }' avRNMR >> vgRNMR
```

Where avRNMR is the input file and vgRNMR is the output file, which is already created with the contents "shift" by another line.

I have also tried a version where print is just set to the mathematical expression instead using "shift" as a variable. Another attempt was putting $ in front of every variable. Neither of these have produced any different results.

The output I get is

```
shift
139.274
2.1268
2.1268
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
```

Which is not the correct answer, particularly considering that my input file only has the six lines shown above. Note that the number of lines with C, H, and other letters is variable.

What I should get is

```
shift
139.27
2.13
NA
NA
NA
```

EDIT

As suggested, exchanging "for(i=2; i<=NR; i++)" for FNR>1 gives the following output

```
 shift
 NA
 C1 45.7006
 139.274
 H40    30.0407
 2.1268
 N41    148.389
 NA
 S44    502.263
 NA
 F45    365.162
 NA
```

Which is almost the correct output for the math answers, but not in the desired format. That first NA also means that a line is getting read to print that, which, if it is truly skipping the first line, shouldn't happen.

Comment: `for(i=2; i<=NR; i++) ` what are you trying to do here.  Normal you loop trough field, not trough records.  You pass line by line, and if all line stored in an array, loop trough them in END section.

Comment: @Jotne I was trying to get it to skip the first line of the input file, as I don't want it to look at the headers.

Comment: To skip first line, just do `NR>1`

Comment: Including that "shift" string in the output that some other code is printing before your awk script runs is needlessly cluttering up your question and making it confusing. It's not part of what you're asking about at all so just get rid of all references to it from  your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the for loop on i=2. Add pattern FNR>1 before the action. Anchor the two patterns to the beginning of the field:

```
awk -v Hslope=$Hslope -v Hint=$Hint -v Cslope=$Cslope -v Cint=$Cint '
FNR > 1 { # skip first record
    if($1 ~ /^C/)      print (($2-Cint)/Cslope)
    else if($1 ~ /^H/) print (($2-Hint)/Hslope)
    else               print "NA"
}' avRNMR >> vgRNMR
```

Warning: I didn't test that code.

**EDIT:** I have now tested the code:

```
$ cat avRNMR
atom Comp
C1   45.7006
H40  30.0407
N41  148.389
S44  502.263
F45  365.162
$ awk -v Hslope=-1.1120 -v Hint=32.4057 -v Cslope=-1.0822 -v Cint=196.4234 '
> FNR > 1 { # skip first record
>     if($1 ~ /^C/)      print (($2-Cint)/Cslope)
>     else if($1 ~ /^H/) print (($2-Hint)/Hslope)
>     else               print "NA"
> }' avRNMR
139.274
2.1268
NA
NA
NA
```

That looks to me like what you want. Please tell me what you are seeing.

Comment: Is there a way to not get it to print what is inputted and just the answer? Also, FNR>1 isn't skipping the first line as evidenced by the NA on the line below shift.

Comment: If FNR isn't working, try NR. It should do the same thing. Also, change >> on the last line to >.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{v[$1]=$2} NR<=FNR||FNR==1{next} /^[CH]/{c=substr($0, 0, 1); print ($2-v[c"int"])/v[c"slope"];next} {print "NA"}' FS="=" vars FS=" " file
139.274
2.1268
NA
NA
NA
```

The first pattern/action pair reads variables from file `vars` into an array `v`. The second skips further processing and also skips the first line for the second file `file`. The third will match lines with `C` and `H` and do the calculations.

You'll need to change the file names and redirect the output to your outfile.

Comment: What is the purpose of redefining the variables when they are already defined in a manner that works? I call them in from a separate file using bash, so I don't really want to mess with their naming.

Comment: It is more flexible since you don't have to make changes to the actual awk call when adding / changing variables. But that's up to you. That part of my answer is just an alternative to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ shift = "NA" }
/^C/ { shift = ($2 - Cint) / Cslope }
/^H/ { shift = ($2 - Hint) / Hslope }
NR>1 { print shift }

$ awk -v Hslope="$Hslope" -v Hint="$Hint" -v Cslope="$Cslope" -v Cint="$Cint" -f tst.awk file
139.274
2.1268
NA
NA
NA
```

or if this is what you really want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ shift = (NR==1 ? "shift" : "NA") }
/^C/ { shift = ($2 - Cint) / Cslope }
/^H/ { shift = ($2 - Hint) / Hslope }
{ print shift }

$ awk -v Hslope="$Hslope" -v Hint="$Hint" -v Cslope="$Cslope" -v Cint="$Cint" -f tst.awk file
shift
139.274
2.1268
NA
NA
NA
```